Resolving compilation error with template specialization
I am having issues in understanding and fixing a compiler error that I see with MinGW (UCRT64) C++20, but that I don't see when I build the code with MSBuild C++11.
header.h: (Only relevant code)
#pragma once
// Has other necessary inclusions
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct Foo {
    // Assumptions:
    // Has some members
    // Has variants of constructors
};

using Fooes = std::multimap<size_t, Foo>;

template <typename S>
std::string retrieveData(S& params, const std::string& tag, const std::string& initval);

extern template bool retrieveData<const Fooes>(const Fooes& params, const std::string& tag, bool initval);

// There are similar such retrieveData `extern template`s which deals with different data types for args and returning
// I have commented them out with the thought that I'll fix one and deal with the remaining later

Source.cpp: (Only relevant code)
// Safe to assume that:
// Has other necessary inclusions
#include <header.h>

Fooes::const_iterator retrieveEntry(const Fooes& params, const std::string& tag) {
    // Impl that is already functional, has no warnings
    }

template<>
std::string retrieveData<const TaxParameters>(const TaxParameters& params, const std::string& tag, const std::string& initval) {
    const auto matchedEntry = retrieveEntry(params, tag);
    if (matchedEntry == params.cend()) {
        return initval;
    }
    return matchedEntry->second.value;
}

// There are similar such retrieveData impl which deals with different data types for args and returning
// I have commented them out with the thought that I'll fix one and deal with the remaining later

Compilation Error that I get:
error: specialization of 'std::string retrieveData(S&, const std::string&, const std::string&) [with S = const std::multimap<long long unsigned int, Foo>; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]' after instantiation
std::string retrieveData<const Fooes>(const Fooes& params, const std::string& tag, const std::string& initval) 

I looked at the CPP reference to understand the Explicit instantiations as I have never worked with those. It talks about usage of extern template in following way:
extern template return-type name < argument-list > ( parameter-list ) ; (3) (since C++11)
extern template return-type name ( parameter-list ) ;   (4) (since C++11)

And,

An explicit instantiation definition forces instantiation of the function or member function they refer to. It may appear in the program anywhere after the template definition, and for a given argument-list, is only allowed to appear once in the program, no diagnostic required.
An explicit instantiation declaration (an extern template) prevents implicit instantiations: the code that would otherwise cause an implicit instantiation has to use the explicit instantiation definition provided somewhere else in the program.

I am so confused to figure out in my code which one is explicit instantiation definition and which one is explicit instantiation declaration, And do I refer to the implementation of the function in source.cpp as Specialization as the compilation error says.
What is the correct way to fix this error?

"Safe to assume that:
// has a header guard
// Has other necessary inclusions" -- There would be no need to assume a header guard if you put all of the example code in one file (one code block). There would be no need to assume the necessary inclusions if you did not remove them (do you need more than <map> and <string>?). Each of these changes would make it easier to copy and compile your code to reproduce your error.

When I copied the two code blocks and added the missing headers, I got a different error: error: template-id 'retrieveData<const alpha::bravo::Fooes>' for 'bool alpha::bravo::retrieveData(const Fooes&, const std::string&, bool)' does not match any template declaration. You might have kept the wrong "similar such retrieveData". Simplifying the code is good, but make sure it still reproduces the error in question. (Also, could you simplify your [mre] more? I don't see why there are namespaces in this code; they look like distractions.)

@JaMiT: My bad, updated. I just read through the spec and found out that adding the explicit specialisation in the header solves the problem. I don't fully understand why.

extern template bool retrieveData<const Fooes>(const Fooes& params, const std::string& tag, bool initval); is simply wrong if your intention is to specialize the template in a .cpp file. What you wrote there is an explicit instantiation declaration, not an explicit specialization declaration as needed. Replace extern template with template<> and then you have the correct syntax.

Of course, the same types need to be specialized by these declarations in the header file as they are in the .cpp file. This isn't clear from your question, where you show a declaration with Fooes and a definition with TaxParameters, which do not seem to match.

This code example seems like overengineering. Seem like this template should work for a single type, so why defining template at all? Also I can see misamtch in template definition and declaration of extern ... (instance of template will be done in different place).

in header.h, the return type of specialization should be
extern template std::string
retrieveData<const Fooes>(const Fooes& params, const std::string& tag, bool initval);

